# Divs not horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`s and I’m trying to align them horizontally. But there are some alignment issues. How can I fix this?

```css
.info {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
.info_label {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.info_data_label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.j {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div className="info">
  <div>
    <div className="info_label">
      <label className="j">Gender</label>
    </div>
    <div className="info_data_label">
      <label className="j">Male</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <div className="info_label">
      <label className="j">Birthday</label>
    </div>
    <div className="info_data_label">
      <label className="j">1992-05-23</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

According to my view it should work correctly. But the second view appears lower to the first `<div>`. They are not correctly aligned.

Comment: Why did you write `className` instead of `class`? The CSS doesn’t get applied this way.

Comment: i'm doing this using react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below CSS, I have only change the margin-right into %, as you are giving the width in % but the margin in pixels.

```
.info {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
.info_label {
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.info_data_label {
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.j {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.info {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  display : inline;

.j {
  float: left;
}

<div className="info" >
      <div className="info" >
      <label className="j">Gender</label>
      <label className="j">Male</label> <br/>
      <label className="j">Birthday</label>
      <label className="j">1992-05-23</label>
</div>
```

This is working as you want dude!

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need , i have added `display:inline-block` and `text-align:center;`

```
.info {
   margin-top: 50px;
   padding-left: 1%;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-align:center;
}
.info_label {
   margin-right: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 0;
   display:inline-block;
   background-color: yellow;
}
.info_data_label {
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: yellow;
   display:inline-block;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4wgd8gk/1/

Answer (score 0):

when i added the CSS `display: inline-block;` to the `.info_label` & `.info_data_labe`l from the console
i found it look a like as per your requirement,
Please check this,.

```
.info_label {
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 40%;
      padding: 0;
      float: left;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
}
.info_data_label {
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use `display:flex` on the parent div https://jsfiddle.net/Lpjxse6L/

Answer (score -2):

https://jsfiddle.net/k4wgd8gk/

See the above example..

you are mentioned the attribute wrong.

`<div className="info_label">` Is this correct format `class` attribute

```css
.info {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
 }
.info_label {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.info_data_label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div>
    <div class="info_label">
      <label className="j">Gender</label>
    </div>
    <div class="info_data_label">
      <label className="j">Male</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <div class="info_label">
      <label className="j">Birthday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="info_data_label">
      <label className="j">1992-05-23</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Attribute class name is not correct...see fiddle link